# Logical statement not evaluating correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to compare 2 numbers, one randomly generated and one obtained from user input.

```
#SkillT is a user-interactive text box, and skills is a dropdown list.
#This is using PyQT5, but I don't think that's pertinent to my question.
Skl = int(SkillT.text())
def calcs():
    a = skills.currentText()
    b = random.randint(0,100)
    if a == "Lethality":
        if b <= Skl:
            print("AAAA")
            print(b)
        else:
            print(b)
```

When I run the program, `b <= Skl` always evaluates to false, even if Skl is set to a number such as 1000. Is there some problem with my code? I am new to Python programming, so please be kind.

Comment: So it does `print(b)`. What is the value of `Skl` and the value of `b`? Make sure it is not `a == "Lethality"` that is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is evaluating to `False`? The most likely reason for your issue is probably that `a != "Lethality". Make sure to check each of the conditions that lead up to that point.